# Map values in list to lists by indicies

Tags: python, numpy

I want to map points in list to lists based off indices in another list.
For example, say we have:

```
k: 2
a: [0,1,2,1]
b: [[i,...], [t,...], [u,...], [v,...]]
```

I want to map the values in `b` to their index from `a` to `c`.

`k` is max value in `a` . I've only put `i,t,u,v` to identify the sub-arrays of `b`.

```
c: [
    [[i,...]],
    [[t,...], [v,...]],
    [[u,...]]
   ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated `a`,`b` and `c` are numpy arrays (ndarrays).

Comment: Is `b` a list of lists or a numpy array?

Comment: @Aryerez It is an `ndarray` sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: Could you clarfy: going from b to c, what's the logic? How come t and v are on another axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def test():
    a = [0,1,2,1]
    k = max(a)
    b = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7], [8, 9]]
    c = [[] for i in range(k+1)]
    for i in range(len(b)):
        c[a[i]].append(b[i])
    print(c)
```